# How to set up X day delivery shipping in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

I need to set up the following ..

- "5 day delivery" $350/product in order
- "7 day delivery" Free
- "Courtesy 15 day delivery" Free

How to do this in Magento?

Comment: $350 for total shipping price or $350 per product in the order? Or - free if there is at least $350 subtotal?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Magento.SE! We're glad you're here. I hate to tell you this but you **can't do this out of the box.** However, it's extremely simple to do this with a paid extension from WebshopApps:

http://www.webshopapps.com/us/shipping/premium-matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

(I'm not affiliated with or endorsed by Webshopapps but they make awesome stuff.)

But not everybody is keen on spending money on extensions. I hesitate to provide a pure code solution so instead I'll recommend you instead just provide this functionality through three shipping methods built-in. The first will be to provide free shipping with a minimum order amount via the built-in **Free Shipping** and then provide the other rates via **Table Rates** and **Flat Rate Shipping**

---

## Step 1: Configure Free Shipping

**1. Navigate to `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods`**

[image]

**2. Set up your free shipping tab to look like the following:**

[image]

This will now display the free shipping option whenever you reach the minimum order amount, and I would suggest that you rename this method to be descriptive: `5 day delivery`.

---

## Step 2: Configure Flat-Rate Shipping

**1. Navigate to `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods`**

[image]

**2. Configure it to look like the following: **

[image]

After you've finished rename this method as well to your preferred `7 day delivery`.

---

## Step 3: Configure Table Rates

We'll use **Table Rates** to display one more shipping option (not two) where shipping will be

**1. Navigate to `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods`**

[image]

**2. Change your `Current Configuration Scope` dropdown to Website:**

[image]

**3. You should now see a button to export the CSV:**

[image]

**4. Download and modify the CSV to include the regions, rates you desire (0.00):**

[image]

Make sure (like the previous two steps) that you rename the shipping method from Table Rates to your preferred method name `Courtesy 15 Day Delivery`.